# PowerMockito not obeying when.thenReturn

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am using PowerMockito to verify the number of calls on a private method: `loadProperties()`.
I also have that method stubbed to return a pre-defined value.

Even though I have the method stubbed, the real implementation is being called, and throwing a `NullPointerException`, since its dependency (the "loader" variable, see snippet below) is not defined (nor should it be) for this test.

As an experiment, I changed the method to be public, and then it works fine!

I am thinking it is a bug in PowerMockito, but I have been wrong about more certain things than this!

Here is the code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DArgumentsLoader.class})
public class TestConfig {
 @Test
 public void testGetPropertyMapCalledOnce() throws Exception {
     Config configMock = mock(Config.class);
     Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
     testMap.put("xx", "xx");
     when(configMock, "loadProperties").thenReturn(testMap);

     when(configMock.getString(anyString(), anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
     // call it twice
     configMock.getString("xx", "yy");
     configMock.getString("xx", "yy");
     // verify loadProperties was only called once
     PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(configMock, times(1)).invoke("loadProperties");
 }
}
```

Just to clarify, the `Config` class looks like this

```
private Map<String, String> loadProperties() throws IOException, HttpException {
    return loader.loadProperties();
}

public String getString(String key, final String defaultValue) {
    String value = getPropertyMap().get(key);
    if(value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

private Map<String, String> getPropertyMap() throws LoadException {
    if(propertyMap == null) {
        propertyMap = loadProperties();
    }
    return propertyMap;
}
```

The `loadProperties()` method should not be called at all, in view of the fact that the tester says

```
when(configMock, "loadProperties").thenReturn(testMap);
```

But it is being called, and it is throwing a `NullPointerException`. Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not preparing the `Config` class for mocking, so `PowerMock` cannot handle it. Just add it to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation, and you should be fine:

```
@PrepareForTest({Config.class, DArgumentsLoader.class})
```